# json_agg() array to object

Tags: c#, postgresql, json.net

**json_agg()** returns result like this

```
 [{..},{..}...]
```

I trying to find is there a way to change this **array** to a **single object**, my result 
is a single object since its returning an array of object I have a problem when
deserialization.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwmsGetDto>(swmsJson.ToString());
```

I tried to find if there is another aggregate function in Postgres SQL for this
but didn't find any.

> My query looks like this :

```
SELECT json_agg(d1) FROM (
  select * from positions;
)d1) as positions;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, `row_to_json()` is the solution
for this problem.

> Example

```
select row_to_json(d1)
from (
  select * from positions where id = 12
) as d1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's returning a collection straight up, you need to deserialize it into that

```
List<SwmsGetDto> array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SwmsGetDto>>(json);
```

If you insist on having a class instead, define one that hold such list.

```
public class SingleObject
{
    public List<SwmsGetDto> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
SingleObject single = new SingleObject() 
{ 
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SwmsGetDto>>(json) 
};
```

Comment: Your help is appreciated, I solved this at the stored procedure level, respect !

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G yw, it's always better to customize the input when possible!